# Calculating sum of elements in a 3D array of huge size

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d

I have created a 3D array with size a[100][100][100]. In the beginning, i was getting some error while compiling the code because of this huge array. As such after a little digging, I declared this array as global and static in my C++ program. Now my requirement is that I have to calculate the sum of all the element of that array. While doing so, I tried looping through the array, and after some time i get a segment fragment error at runtime.

Can anyone advice as to how i should go about it? Is there a better approach for calculating the sum?

Thanks

My code is given here

```
for(int m=0;m<dimension;m++){
        for(int j=0;j<dimension;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<dimension;k++){
                a[m][j][k]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how i am calculating the sum

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=x1;i<=x2;i++){
    for(int j=y1;j<=y2;j++){
        for(int k=z1;k<=z2;k++){
            sum=sum+a[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

where x1,x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 are taken as user input.

I dont get any error in the first part but in the second part of the code where segmentation fault error is thrown.

Comment: How are you assigning values to that array?

Comment: Firstly, I am assigning all the values of that array as 0.After that according to user need, I am directly assigning values to the array. For example
a[23][45][50]=something. And then i calculate the sum.

Comment: Your problem description is a bit vague, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Some code, please.

Comment: `for(int m=0;m<dimension;m++){
            for(int j=0;j<dimension;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<dimension;k++){
                    a[m][j][k]=0;
                }
            }
        }`
This is how i am assigning values where the dimension is taken as user input.

`for(int i=x1;i<=x2;i++){
        for(int j=y1;j<=y2;j++){
            for(int k=z1;k<=z2;k++){
                sum=sum+a[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }`
This is how i am calculating the sum of the elements of the array where x,y and z values are taken as input again.

Comment: it mainly calculates the sum within an interval of the array as input by the user

Comment: could you edit your question and add the code in your comment for better readability.

Comment: As for a better way to do it: in high-performance code, you could insert an OMP directive to turn a loop like that into a collapsed reduction operation for SIMD.  That parallelizes it.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, and I think that you go over the size allowed by your system. With an 8 bit int (on 64bit) and 1000*1000*1000 you are at 7.4 Gb. On windows systems 2Gb I think is allowed per program normally. At what size does it get the error.

Comment: Thanks Davisor...although i have no idea how to use OMP..will check it

Comment: can you give us the input parameters (x1, x2, etc...)? I tried it with `int x1 = 5, x2 = 95, y1 = 15, y2 = 75, z1 = 1, z2 = 98;` and the whole thing worked and took 6 ms.

Answer (score 2):

In your second code fragment, you use user input as your array dimensions without bounds checking.  Always, *always*, ***always*** bounds-check your array accesses.

A fast-and-dirty way of doing so in this case is:

```
assert(x1 >= 0); // Unless x1 is unsigned.
assert(y1 >= 0); // Unless y1 is unsigned.
assert(z1 >= 0); // Unless z1 is unsigned.
assert(x2 < dimension);
assert(y2 < dimension);
assert(z2 < dimension);
```

Also check the initialization of a.  If it’s dynamically-allocated, check the return code.

Or replace with code to recover from the error.  The runtime cost is negligible, as you are doing this outside your loop.  Also, if your dimension is declared as `constexpr size_t dimension = 100;` and `a` is declared as `static int a[dimension][dimension][dimension];` (or a reference to an array with known bounds), you can replace the first loop with,

```
memset( &a, 0, sizeof(a) );
```

Otherwise, for a dynamic array, you can use:

```
memset( &a, 0, sizeof(int)*dimension*dimension*dimension );
```

However, a statically-allocated global array will be initialized to zeroes already, when the program starts.

If you use `std::array`, it will do the bounds-checking for you with no extra memory overhead.

Comment: Thanks Davisor...but the input provided by me is not surpassing the bounds...as such this is apparently not the problem.

Comment: Run in a debugger, then, and see where it crashes.

Comment: Also, even if you “know” that’s not the problem, check your bounds anyway.  And make sure the array is allocated correctly.  If you allocated the correct amount of memory, and your accesses are in bounds, you should not be getting segfaults.

Comment: This is why you should post a MCVE. Your first post had no code; this code does not show the initialization of any of your variables.

Comment: @OP: you have <= in the 2nd loop and < in the first loop. A value of x2,y2 or z2 == 100 will cause a segfault. Be sure that the edge condition is not triggered. Try and show *exactly* what inputs you're putting in there.

Comment: @JasonLang Was that comment meant for me or the OP? Ain’t my loop.

Comment: yeah sorry it was for the OP, since he was questioning the need for bounds checking, i was pointing out the edge condition which could be triggering the failure. He might well have put a right-bound of 100 in there expecting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a great idea to use 3D-arrays
You could try to sum with only one for loop, as follows, though, to avoid nesting:

```
int D = dimension;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < D*D*D; ++i)
        sum += A[i / (D * D)][(i / D) % D][i % D];
```

Comment: that was interesting...although i dont think that would serve the purpose because my array here does not neccessarily start from 0 and ends at the last element. Like i mentioned, the start position of x, y, z and the end position of the same will be taken as user input, thereby calculating the sum within a particular interval of the array

Comment: I tried to run a program that assigns random values to `int [100][100][100] `and then calculates the sum and it took 1-10 ms to complete (both for loop and this way). Then I tried `int [1000][1000][1000]` and I got a `segmentation fault` when declaring the array. Are you sure the problem is during the process, and not the array declaration?

Comment: I dont get any compilation error while declaring the array.

Comment: were you able to find out the sum within a particular interval for example from [21][76][99] to [76][98][5]...??

Comment: For some reason it works for me only when I have a static array, but not a dynamic.

Comment: All those % commands are slow however. It's better to make a 1D-array and a custom accessor, then using a linear summation without that added maths.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not the answer you we're hoping for. I would switch to boost multi_array. With declaring a standard array of size 1000 or even 100 I can reproduce your problem. With the boost multi-array I do not have that problem. See below the code:

```
//Boost:ublas
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <cassert>

//Using declarations
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

int main() {
    cout << "Start Time: " << time(0) << endl;
    time_t t0 = time(0);

    //Example taken and adjusted from: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html
// Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    int const size =1000;
    array_type A(boost::extents[size][size][size]);

    // Assign values to the elements
    for (index i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != size; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != size; ++k)
                A[i][j][k] = 1;

    // Verify values
    int sum = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != size; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != size; ++k)
                sum += A[i][j][k];

    std::cout << "Sum:  " << sum << endl;

    cout << "End Time: " << time(0) << endl;
    time_t t1 = time(0);

return 0;
}
```

Hope this can solve your problem.

As mentioned earlier in my comment, I think your problem is that you are claiming more memory than your operating systems allows without special considerations, but I can't confirm this readily.

Just in case you don't know boost, the Boost libraries are a great toolbox with lots of functionality and have contributed a lot to the C++ standard over the years. So I would recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks Klomp ... will check it